# How do I convert a complex number?

Tags: python

I built a calculator for a bio equation, and I think I've narrowed down the source of my problem, which is a natural log I take:

```
goldman = ((R * T) / F) * cmath.log(float(top_row) / float(bot_row))

print("Membrane potential: " + str(goldman) + "V"
```

My problem is that it will only display the output in a complex form:

```
Membrane potential: (0.005100608207126714+0j)V
```

Is there any way of getting this to print as a floating number? Nothing I've tried has worked.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Complex numbers have a real part and an imaginary part:

```
>>> c = complex(1, 0)
>>> c
(1+0j)
>>> c.real
1.0
```

It looks like you just want the real part... so:

```
print("Membrane potential: " + str(goldman.real) + "V"
```

Comment: While this answer may work, it is not as correct as the answer using math.log

Answer (score 7):

Use `math.log` instead of `cmath.log`.

Since you don't want the imaginary part of the result, it would be better to use `math.log` instead of `cmath.log`.  This way, you'll get an error if your input is not in the valid domain for a real `log`, which is much better than silently giving you meaningless results (for example, if `top_row` is negative).  Also, complex numbered results make no sense for this particular equation.

ie, use:

```
goldman = ((R * T) / F) * math.log(float(top_row) / float(bot_row))
```

Comment: Great observation, but it should be a comment.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I completely disagree.  Althought It's not an answer to the literal headline question, it's the correct answer to the actual problem the OP facing.  It would be a serious mistake to use `.real` for this problem rather than `math.log`.  The real question here is, "I get a complex term that I wasn't expecting", not how to get rid of it.

Comment: If you can edit the answer to include a code sample showing your implementation, then yes. I am not disagreeing with your observation, but as written it could be improved to make it into an answer.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Seems questionable that this would add clarity, but it's there now...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just convert it to float value you can do this:

```
def print_float(x1):
a=x1.real
b=x1.imag
val=a+b
print(val)
```

`ec=complex(2,3)`

In this way you can actually get the floating value.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple if you need only real part of the complex number.

```
goldman = 0.005100608207126714+0j  
print(goldman)  
(0.005100608207126714+0j)  

goldman = float(goldman.real)  
print(goldman)  
0.005100608207126714
```

If you need absolute value then use following

```
goldman = 0.005100608207126714+0j  
print(goldman)  
(0.005100608207126714+0j)  

goldman = float(abs(goldman))  
print(goldman)  
0.005100608207126714  
print(type(goldman))  
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: Hi @Saud. You can improve the readability of your answer by using the text format options.