# How to avoid complex numbers and get floats?

Tags: python

this our first Homework and we struggle a problem.We try to create a code for a curve sketching, but Our problem is that we have to put some results in another function to get to our goal. We just get complex numbers for result but need floats.

How can we avoid getting complex numbers in the first place?

```
from sympy import *

function = input("function =")  #x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 for example

n1 = solve(function,x)

for n1 in solve(function,x): 
   print("n1 :",(N(n1)))
```

Comment: can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35423928/how-do-i-convert-a-complex-number

Comment: well, this polynomial has complex roots, so how do you want to "avoid" complex? Pick a polynomial with only real roots? Take its real part or its modulus?

Comment: The first call to `solve` is superfluous. You do not use the result and the variable name is reused, which delegates the previous result to the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if the result is real:

```
from sympy import *

x = symbol.Symbol("x")

function = input("function =")  #x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 for example

n1 = solve(function,x)

for n1 in solve(function,x): 
    if n1.is_real:
        print("n1 :",(N(n1)))
```

The other roots are still there, but now you only see the ones in real space.

Answer (score 0):

Your example (`x**5 + x**4 + x**3 + x**2 + x + 1`) is a 5th order polynomial so it can have up to 5 roots. In this case [there is only one real root, and the rest are complex](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%2B1%3D0).

Hence the output is exactly what you would expect

```
n1 : -1.00000000000000
n1 : -0.5 - 0.866025403784439*I
n1 : -0.5 + 0.866025403784439*I
n1 : 0.5 - 0.866025403784439*I
n1 : 0.5 + 0.866025403784439*I
```